# Embedding a notion page in an HTML page

Tags: html

I'm having trouble finding a way to embed a notion page in an html page. I use iframes to embed spreadsheets but Notion doesn't allow that. Is there any way to do that?

```
<iframe loading="lazy" src="https://dusty-agate-32f.notion.site/b52eb9b2cf3845c4a59128b7ce1c2228?v=7a8a1bb42918428d8e4b7991214cf2b7"></iframe>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the iframe to work, first make sure the Notion page is public.
Secondly, there isn't an official way to do it, according to this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Notion/comments/apwqrp/is_there_a_way_to_embed_a_notion_page_on_another/).

As an alternative, you can export as HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same issue, it looks like Notion doesn't allow iframes, it blocks the requests.
I found this tool online: [www.notioniframe.com](https://www.notioniframe.com/) to generate an embeddable URL and the iframe HTML code to include it in any web.

Comment: could you describe within your answer what the online tool does? I know users can go to the linked website. But it's good to have a description of the answer here at stackoverflow.com .

Comment: sure, it basically generates a new URL for the notion page and the iframe HTML to include it in any other page. I just edited the answer with more details about the usage

Comment: I am trying to embed a private notion page, and the page contains links for other pages, but the created link using this tool is only showing me the page without the links to other pages

Answer (score 0):

The only options are:

- using the official Notion API
- using tools like [embednpages.com](https://www.embednpages.com) that generates an iframe snippet for your Notion page.